# Reading file consists of float number with mmap() in C++

Tags: c++, scanf, mmap

I'm trying to read a file consists of 100000000 float numbers like *0.12345678* or *-0.1234567* separated by space in c++. I used *fscanf()* to read the file and the codes is like this:

```
FILE *fid = fopen("testingfile.txt", "r");
if (fid == NULL)
    return false;

float v;

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    fscanf(fid, "%f", &v);

fclose(fid);
```

The file is 1199999988 bytes in size and took around ***18 seconds*** to finish reading using *fscanf()*.Therefore, I would like to use *mmap()* to speed up the reading and code is like this:

```
#define FILEPATH "testingfile.txt"

char text[10] = {'\0'};
struct stat s;
int status = stat(FILEPATH, &s);
int fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1)
{
    perror("Error opening file for reading");
    return 0;
}

char *map = (char *)mmap(NULL, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
close(fd);

if (map == MAP_FAILED)
{
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0,j=0; i < s.st_size; i++)
{
    if (isspace(map[i]))
    {
        text[j] = '\0';
        j = 0;
        float v = atof(text);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            text[j] = '\0';
        continue;
    }
    text[j] = map[i];
    j++;

}
if (munmap(map, s.st_size) == -1)
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, it still takes around ***14.5 seconds*** to finish reading. I found the most time consuming part is converting array to float,which consumes around ***10 seconds***

So I have three questions:

1. Is there any way I can directly read float instead of char or
2. Is there any better method to convert char array to float
3. How does `fscanf` recognize floating point value and read it, which is much faster than `atof()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. No. 2. No.  Converting a text string to a native floating point value is a deceptively complicated process. Native floating point values are essentially expressed as `m*2^n` where `m` is a number in the range [1,2). Given a series of decimal characters, with an optional decimal point, do you know exactly how to derive `m` and `n`? Good luck with that. You're already ahead of the game by using raw C library functions. If you were to use native C++ formatted extraction operators, this'll probably take 20-30% longer.

Comment: Why would mmap() be any faster than reading in the data the old fashioned way?  Either way the same amount of data will be read in from the disk, and on a modern computer the disk is going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: A more promising approach, if you want to minimize load time, would be to store the float values in native-endian binary format rather than ASCII (i.e. each float value in the file would occupy exactly 4 bytes and you could then mmap() the file and just cast a const-float-pointer directly to the mmap'd memory region and access the floats directly)

Comment: Some years ago, we wrote a [COLLADA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) importer (COLLADA is an XML file format for 3D data which usually contains lots of floating point values to describe 3D vertices). We replaced `strtod()` by an own implementation (you can find some with google). (Be aware that `strtod()` may consider the locale which is undesirable in this case.) Finally, we got a _huge_ speed-up of 60 ... 100 which I had never expected. Practically, file loading reduced to a few seconds (instead of a few _minutes_).

Comment: Have you tried using `std::stringstream`? If your numbers are in plain text, that should be a viable option (and you avoid all that ugly C code too). `mmap` the file and treat it like a `char const *`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I compared the reading speed when both of them read 1199999988 bytes char (without converting to float). The latter one is way faster than fscanf(). I'm wondering how fscanf() recognize floating point value and read it, which makes both method have similar reading speed when reading float.

Comment: For question 3, `fscanf()` is likely to be faster because stdio buffering anticipates sequential read (so does a reasonable amount of read-ahead).  It's likely that your `mmap()` expects random access (you didn't specify `MAP_POPULATE`), so doesn't pre-fetch pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the advice given, here are two possible solutions to this problem:

The first approach would be a bit "stupid". Since the format of floating number values stored is known, conversion from char array to float number can be easily done without using`atof()`.
By removing `atof()`, it only takes ***8 seconds*** to finish reading and conversion for the same file.

The second approach is to change the store format of float numbers in the file (as advised by Jeremy Friesner). Floating number values are stored in binary format so that conversion part for `mmap()` is not required. The code becomes something like this:

```
#define FILEPATH "myfile.bin"

int main()
{
int start_s = clock();
struct stat s;
int status = stat(FILEPATH, &s);

int fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1)
{
    perror("Error opening file for reading");
    return 0;
}

float *map = (float *)mmap(NULL, s.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
close(fd);

if (map == MAP_FAILED)
{
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < s.st_size / 4; i++)
{
    float v = map[i];
}

if (munmap(map, s.st_size) == -1)
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

This would dramatically reduce the time required to read the file in same size.